# Spring MVC like processing of AMQP messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration, spring-amqp

What I want to do is process AMQP messages in a very similar way the Http Requests are processed using *spring-webmvc* annotations such as *@RequestMapping*, *@RequestParam* etc. But, instead of the Http Request my source object will be an AMQP message. The AMQP message request will have two headers, for example -

```
method="POST"
url="/api/myobjects/{someParam}"
```

and the payload will contain data in json format.

If you have noticed, this is nothing but HTTP REST api mapped to AMQP message.
I want to be able to write a controller like handler, for example -

```
@Controller
public class MyObjectHandler {

    @RequestMapping(value="/api/myobjects/{someParam}", method="POST")
    public MyObject createMyObject(@Payload MyObject myObj, @PathParam String someParam) {
        //... some processing
        return myObj;
    }
    // ...more handlers
}
```

I have looked at `spring-amqp/rabbitmq` annotations and also `spring integration` annotations. They are close to what I want, but would not allow routing to handler methods based on header parameters, especially the REST url.

I don't expect that a readymade solution would be available for this. Just want to make sure I choose the best possible option. Some of the options I think are (in order of precedence)

- If the spring-webmvc annotation processing mechanism is extensible, just extend it to use AMQP message as source instead of Http Request
- Modify the spring-webmvc annotation processing mechanism to take the AMQP message as input instead of Http Request
- Write your own solution with custom annotaions and their processors, which I think is a very involving task
- Or any other possible approach than above?

Any guidance/direction is appreciated.

Comment: I would leave spring-mvc alone and write some amqp to http layer, seems easier to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the starting point is likely `AbstractMethodMessageHandler` in spring-messaging.

There's currently a `SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler` implementation for websockets which invokes `@Controller`s.

You could use a `@RabbisListener` method that has a `Message<?>` parameter (Spring AMQP will convert the underlying Rabbit message to a spring-messaging message, including the headers). Then, invoke the message handler to route to the appropriate controller method.

If you come up with a robust implementation, please consider [contributing it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/wiki).